# Is it possible to install Signalr with vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, signalr

I am trying to install SignalR in my vs2010 project and I get the following error -

**Could not install package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.0.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.**

How can I install SignalR on vs2010 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution you are looking for,
http://rionscode.wordpress.com/2013/04/06/getting-signalr-ready-in-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: Hi, I followed the solution you recomend and I got the following error message from Nuget -

Install failed. Rolling back…
Could not install package ‘Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.0.1′. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets ‘.NETFramework,Version=v4.0′, but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install 1.x

```
>Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.1.3
```

2.x requires 4.5 of the framework

Comment: I used 1.2.2  and also needed Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26224042/1415038

Answer (score 1):

v1.2.2 is the last version of SignalR for the Visual Studio 2010 with .Net Framework 4.0

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.2.2
```