# SignalR .NET4 Map issue

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I created a .net framework 4.0 with SignalR downloaded from Nuget. I think I downloaded Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.1.3  (based on instructions from [SignalR support in .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607252/signalr-support-in-net-4))

Then I copied the code from application  http://blog.robseder.com/2013/10/18/executing-a-long-running-process-from-a-web-page/

When I execute it I am getting an error below

*Error  10  'Owin.IAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'MapSignalR' and no extension method 'MapSignalR' accepting a first argument of type 'Owin.IAppBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Anyone help me to fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

namespace MvcApplication1.App_Start
{
    public static class Startup
    {
        public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I have these in my MVC project .net Framework 4.0

Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core 1.2.2.0
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin 1.2.2.0
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb 1.2.2.0
Microsoft.Owin 2.1.0.0
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 1.0.0.0

But I don't see Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.dll!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057459/owin-iappbuilder-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-mapsignalr

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate. Mine is .net Framework 4.0 and I am using SignalR 1.1.3

Comment: @Pawel sorry! I got it wrong. I still receive the same error. add more details to main post.

Comment: out of curiosity - why do you use 1.1.3 instead of the latest?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably late to answer this post. Might be helpful for someone else.
`Startup.cs` doesn't support version 4.0
You will need a `global.asax` with following

```
using System.Web.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I also ran into same issue and after updating Owin version all is working fine

Also @[Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1168070/pawel) has suggested the same

```
Package manager console : Install-Package Microsoft.Owin -Version 2.1.0
```

Comment: I added the Microsoft.Owin, I still see the same error. Also, I tried to add Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.0.1 but it failed. my using has both Owin and Microsoft.Owin

Comment: For your reference I am adding code in the main post. Please take a look. in my MVC project references I have Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin 1.2.2.0 and Microsoft.Owin 2.0.1.0 and Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 1.0.0.0

Comment: @CoolArchTek i just checked my code to see version of owin it is `2.1.0` can you just try with this version bcoz i have also same error and i resolved t using Owin version

Comment: I still receive the same error. add more details to main post.