# Connect a .NET SignalR client (Windows XP/.NET framework 4.0) to a signalR v2 server

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, signalr, signalr.client

Can I connect a .NET SignalR C# client (Windows XP/.NET framework 4.0) to a signalR v2 server (ASP.NET, SignalR hosted on Mono)?

I know I won't be able to use Websockets from Windows XP but if this setup is possible I will benefit by being able to connect newer Windows clients (Windwos 8+) using Websockets.

Comment: Windows XP is dead, while SignalR on Mono is unofficial so why do you want to go with such a bad approach?

Comment: The clients run on windows (XP, 7, 10). I want to be able to connect to SignalR server from all of them. I can switch from Mono server to Windows server if this is required.

Comment: Before Microsoft ships SignalR on .NET Core officially, the server might be a Windows Server. Microsoft no longer supports Windows XP, nor anything older than .NET Framework 4.5.2. So you know what baseline you should set for the product. Then you can test whether everything works (it should).

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to my question is that it is possible to connect a .NET SignalR client (Windows XP/.NET framework 4.0) to a signalR v2 server.

As described [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#clientsetup): "If the version of SignalR that you have on the client is different from the version that you have on the server, SignalR is often able to adapt to the difference. For example, a server running SignalR version 2 will support clients that have 1.1.x installed as well as clients that have version 2 installed."

Also, as @sanchezis suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26224042/3218944), version 1.2.2 of SignalR is supported in .NET framework 4 which can be installed in Windows XP.